# Detect hardware graphics support

Tags: python, windows, graphics, hardware

I am looking for a way to programatically differentiate between running on a machine with hardware graphics support, for example

[image]

as opposed to running without hardware drivers, in which case I'll revert to software rendering

[image]

I've tried using the [`wmi`](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) module, however in the former case when graphics hardware was available, I can find nothing in the video controllers that indicates they were properly detected

```
import wmi
pc = wmi.WMI()
for graphics in pc.Win32_VideoController():
    print(graphics.properties)
```

Output

```
{'AcceleratorCapabilities': None, 'AdapterCompatibility': None, 'AdapterDACType': None, 'AdapterRAM': None, 'Availability': None, 'CapabilityDescriptions': None, 'Caption': None, 'ColorTableEntries': None, 'ConfigManagerErrorCode': None, 'ConfigManagerUserConfig': None, 'CreationClassName': None, 'CurrentBitsPerPixel': None, 'CurrentHorizontalResolution': None, 'CurrentNumberOfColors': None, 'CurrentNumberOfColumns': None, 'CurrentNumberOfRows': None, 'CurrentRefreshRate': None, 'CurrentScanMode': None, 'CurrentVerticalResolution': None, 'Description': None, 'DeviceID': None, 'DeviceSpecificPens': None, 'DitherType': None, 'DriverDate': None, 'DriverVersion': None, 'ErrorCleared': None, 'ErrorDescription': None, 'ICMIntent': None, 'ICMMethod': None, 'InfFilename': None, 'InfSection': None, 'InstallDate': None, 'InstalledDisplayDrivers': None, 'LastErrorCode': None, 'MaxMemorySupported': None, 'MaxNumberControlled': None, 'MaxRefreshRate': None, 'MinRefreshRate': None, 'Monochrome': None, 'Name': None, 'NumberOfColorPlanes': None, 'NumberOfVideoPages': None, 'PNPDeviceID': None, 'PowerManagementCapabilities': None, 'PowerManagementSupported': None, 'ProtocolSupported': None, 'ReservedSystemPaletteEntries': None, 'SpecificationVersion': None, 'Status': None, 'StatusInfo': None, 'SystemCreationClassName': None, 'SystemName': None, 'SystemPaletteEntries': None, 'TimeOfLastReset': None, 'VideoArchitecture': None, 'VideoMemoryType': None, 'VideoMode': None, 'VideoModeDescription': None, 'VideoProcessor': None}
{'AcceleratorCapabilities': None, 'AdapterCompatibility': None, 'AdapterDACType': None, 'AdapterRAM': None, 'Availability': None, 'CapabilityDescriptions': None, 'Caption': None, 'ColorTableEntries': None, 'ConfigManagerErrorCode': None, 'ConfigManagerUserConfig': None, 'CreationClassName': None, 'CurrentBitsPerPixel': None, 'CurrentHorizontalResolution': None, 'CurrentNumberOfColors': None, 'CurrentNumberOfColumns': None, 'CurrentNumberOfRows': None, 'CurrentRefreshRate': None, 'CurrentScanMode': None, 'CurrentVerticalResolution': None, 'Description': None, 'DeviceID': None, 'DeviceSpecificPens': None, 'DitherType': None, 'DriverDate': None, 'DriverVersion': None, 'ErrorCleared': None, 'ErrorDescription': None, 'ICMIntent': None, 'ICMMethod': None, 'InfFilename': None, 'InfSection': None, 'InstallDate': None, 'InstalledDisplayDrivers': None, 'LastErrorCode': None, 'MaxMemorySupported': None, 'MaxNumberControlled': None, 'MaxRefreshRate': None, 'MinRefreshRate': None, 'Monochrome': None, 'Name': None, 'NumberOfColorPlanes': None, 'NumberOfVideoPages': None, 'PNPDeviceID': None, 'PowerManagementCapabilities': None, 'PowerManagementSupported': None, 'ProtocolSupported': None, 'ReservedSystemPaletteEntries': None, 'SpecificationVersion': None, 'Status': None, 'StatusInfo': None, 'SystemCreationClassName': None, 'SystemName': None, 'SystemPaletteEntries': None, 'TimeOfLastReset': None, 'VideoArchitecture': None, 'VideoMemoryType': None, 'VideoMode': None, 'VideoModeDescription': None, 'VideoProcessor': None}
```

If it matters, I will be targeting a Windows system, in case there is an OS-specific solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use [`infi.devicemanager`](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.devicemanager) to detect if `'Microsoft Basic Display Driver'` is listed in the device descriptions, which would indicate lack of hardware graphics support.

```
from infi.devicemanager import DeviceManager

def has_hardware_graphics():
    dm = DeviceManager()
    return all(dev.description != 'Microsoft Basic Display Driver' for dev in dm.all_devices)
```